# import and assign multiple files loadtxt

Tags: python, text, import

Sorry I know this should be very easy. I would like to load 6 text files and assign these to 6 variables e.g. file1 to xl, file 2 to xr etc. I don't think I understand how to work through the list properly. I have tried using the for i in range(6), itertools and enumerate but none seems to do what I want.

```
files = ['f1.txt','f2.txt','f3.txt','f4.txt','f5.txt','f6.txt']

for file in files:
    xl,xr,yl,yr,zl,zr = np.loadtxt(file)
```

I think i could use the append function but this creates one rather than 6 variables I think

Comment: The `for file in files` loop returns one element of the `files`-list per iteration, So you would overwrite all those variables with the (unpacked) output of `np.loadtxt(file)`. Do you really need 6 different variables? Why not use a `list`, like you are already doing with the filenames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could open all the files and store the results with a list-comprehension:

```
files = ['f1.txt','f2.txt','f3.txt','f4.txt','f5.txt','f6.txt']
loaded = [np.loadtxt(file) for file in files]
```

you would have to access them with `loaded[0]` etc... or directly assign:

```
xl, xr, yl, yr, zl, zr = [np.loadtxt(file) for file in files]
```

if you insist on the original variable names.

Comment: Right now it is only a list comprehension, or am I missing something?

Comment: @ChristianKönig no, you are not missing anythig - you caught an evil typo... thanks!

Comment: Thanks both. Makes sense now why the original did not work. Looks easy now I've seen the answer... :-)